# HDC to HDC for HDC

Tags: c, windows

I would like to blit hdc to an other hdc, and this hdc will be blit into hdc containing "BeginPaint". But a problem appears, nothing have been drawn.

this is the code, thanks,

```c
HDC hdcMem3 = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);


SelectObject(hdcMem3, Picture);

BITMAP bitmap;
GetObject(Picture, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);


HDC hdcMem2 = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
BitBlt(hdcMem2, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem3, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
DeleteDC(hdcMem3);
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
DeleteDC(hdcMem2);
```

Comment: Have you looked at any decent tutorials, or _[example code](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html)_.  Read to the bottom.  It covers 3 ways of Creating/Destroying an HDC, that may help you.  Or this _[copy & paste](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6710/Using-BitBlt-to-Copy-and-Paste-Graphics)_ example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateCompatibleDC` creates a device context with a 1-pixel monochrome bitmap.

In your example, the device context referenced by `hdcMem3` has a real bitmap, but the DC referenced by `hdcMem2` has only the 1-pixel monochrome bitmap.  When you blit from `hdcMem3` to `hdcMem2`, you probably end up with 1 black pixel.

What you need is to create a memory bitmap to select into `hdcMem2`.  I assume that, eventually, you're going to display this in a window.  Let's assume that you have a device context for the window called `hdcWindow`.

```
// Create a memory bitmap that's compatible with the window (screen) and
// the same size as Picture.
hbmpMem2 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight);
hbmpOld2 = SelectObject(hdcMem2, hbmpMem2);
```

Now when you do stuff to hdcMem2, it will draw to a real bitmap.

When you're done with `hdcMem2`, you need to first take care of `hbmpMem2`:

```
SelectObject(hdcMem2, hbmpOld2);
DeleteObject(hbmpMem2);
DestroyDC(hdcMem2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay work ! but i've found one thing see :

```html
                  BITMAP bitmap;
                  GetObject(picture, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
                  LPBITMAPINFO Hbitmap = new BITMAPINFO;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(Hbitmap->bmiHeader);
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biWidth = 300;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biHeight = 300;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 300 * 4 * 300;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
                  Hbitmap->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;


                  HDC hdcMem3 = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
                     SelectObject(hdcMem3, picture);
                     HDC hdcMem2 = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
                        HBITMAP BhdcMem2 = CreateDIBSection(hdcMem2, Hbitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS,0, 0, 0);
                        SelectObject(hdcMem2, BhdcMem2);
                        BitBlt(hdcMem2, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem3, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                        BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                     DeleteDC(hdcMem2);
                  DeleteDC(hdcMem3);
                  delete Hbitmap;
```